# Does this library have a way of showing a world map?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Does Chart.js have a way of showing a world map or should I look at another lib. Or could I overlay a chart js chart over a world map img?

What I want to be able to do make a bubble char over a world map.

Answer (score 3):

No, chart.js doesn't show a world map! but you can use a map library (such as leaflet or mapbox) and then overlay your chart on the map that you have created.

leaflet documentation:

https://leafletjs.com/

mapbox documentation:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

edit: if you want to draw some shapes (like circle ) on the map, the above libraries do that themselves.

Comment: D3.js is good with maps as well. But that might be too much for a simple map...

Comment: Yeah i think it's a large library @HeadhunterKev